# How could I do interval for Subject pipe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this actions:

```
message$ = new Subject();
    
    method() {
        return this.message$.pipe(scan((acc, val) => [...acc, val] []))
    }
    
     method.subscribe()
```

I would like to get a value with an interval of 1 sec. so then I can have a control of getting values from the server.

I would be glad if someone shows how can do this. Thanks.

Comment: Here is an example that can help you achieve the same: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan

Answer (score 2):

You can use interval from RxJs which creates an Observable that emits sequential numbers with a specific interval.

like this:

```
obs$ = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo("Im emtting this every second"))
```

Then you could subscribe to obs$ and then get your value each 1000 ms.

Normally when working with subjects you won't subscribe to them directly and you won't expose them to the outer world. Since a subject is an observable and an observer this could mess up things.

So it's common to do the follwoing:

```
private sub = new Subject();
public const obs$ = sub.asObservable()
```

If you want to cache the value you can use a BeaviorSubject instead, so late subscribers will also get the last value. You could also have a public method that can call next on the subject.

I don't know if you want to send a request every second or if you want to accumulate all the responses. If you want to accumulate the responses you can use the scan operator.

A simple example without accumulation the response is something like this:

```
  httpPoller(): Observable<responseDTO>{
    return interval(1000).pipe(switchMap(() => this.fetchData()));
  }


  fetchData(): Observable<responseDTO> {
    return this.http.get<responseDTO>("www.mybackend.com");
  }
```

Then you can subscribe to this somewhere in your code. Remember to unsubscribe to the observable if you are using it in a component that gets created multiple times.
The switchmap is used to chain the two observables, and it will cancel the execution of the inner observable if the outer emits a value.
The switchmap will cancel the request if the data is not received before the next emit. If you dont wan't that behavior you could replace it with e.g. concatMap which will call the backend for every emit of interval.
You could also use exhaustMap instead. Then the inner observable(http request) will ignore emits from the outer observable if it's not done.